# Where to store contiguous arrays of components?

Tags: c++, entity-system, component-based

I've been working on an entity component system and have the trouble of where to define/put the arrays of each component type. Each component type is user defined so I do not know what or how many arrays to create so I am guessing I need to do something with templates.

This is what I have done so far with example usage. I am rather confused and not sure if what I have done so far is the way to go about this.

```
template<class T>
class Component
{
public:

    Component() = default;
    virtual ~Component() {};

private:

    friend class Entity;

    uint64 m_entity_id;

    static std::vector<T> COMPONENTS;

};
```

Example component:

```
class Velocity : public Component<Velocity>
{
public:

    ~Velocity();

    float get_x() const;

    float get_y() const;

private:

    float x;
    float y;

};
```

The idea is that this would create a static array for each component type. This feels like a weird way to achieve my goal but I can't think of any other way.

Have I missed an obvious solution to this problem?

Comment: And what happens when a newly supplied component wishes to use a different storage mechanism than a `std::vector`?  If your component is meant to be nothing more than data, that's all it should be.  You should abstract away the storage mechanism as @PSquall suggests in order to allow that flexibility.  What a lot of people get caught up in is storing the actual component class contiguously and that isn't always necessary.  That class is meant to be "glue" per-se and a system or some other storage solution might storage attributes of a component in individual arrays for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you described is using the so called "curiously recurring template pattern", often abbreviated as CRTP and is very common in C++ programming.

This is a straightforward solution to the problem at hand and I use it in my entity component system in the same way. It is in not weird and seems to be the standard way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This question is depending on more factors based on what you want to do.
First you said, you want the components to be user defined, so i guess you are working on a game library/engine for multiple game uses.

LukeG's answer with the CRTP is the right way to answer the "how to" part of you question. Problem is, you need a system to register the content the user has defined. You can't just use classes a user has defined.

That's why i suggest some sort of manager, where you register each used component type, that creates the array for the component. This will be useful if you want to reference those components in more than one part of your design, without that part knowing, if this component is registered or not. 
You can also use that component manager for multithreading or network purposes later on.

In my library i have a data manager for that, where every other manager registers the component it will need. You will need something similar, since your components need to be user defined, your managers will need the same.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a component manager. I don't see what it provides over my current solution. Why can't I just use classes a user has defined. E.g `template<class T> Entity::add_component(Component<T> c);`

Comment: E.g. you have your Velocity Component. Your user knows how it works and what members it has, but your GraphicsManager does not. So the user has to define his own GraphicsManager, that knows the components the user has implemented. If you have more than one Manager, that needs the position, like the AI or Collision detection and so on. you need an overarching manager for the components to give you the components you want. Else every manager needs to know every manager with the same components. Hard to describe any better in a comment!

Comment: If I understand you correctly you're basically talking about how the components get used as they are just data holders? For example, the Velocity component is needed for physics, collision etc and a Transform conponent would be needed for physics, collision and rendering etc.

Comment: Yes, sort of. If it's pure data holder or as a container for functions, that doesn't matter. The problem is, something will want access to to a shared component, either to modify or to use it. And in either case, the manager that calls the components needs to know what it returns. If you allow custom components, you either have to implement the functions in the Base class (crtp approach)  or the manager is hard coded by the user.

Comment: I see, you are correct. What you can't see from my code above is the Entity and System parts of the ECS I am creating so I already have what you are talking about handled with System which the user will create along with Components. I am going to leave my accepted answer with LukeG as he actually gave me the answer to my initial question. This is equally valid though. Thanks!

Comment: That's OK, just wanted to add that for completion sake.